# JAX-WS Service consumed by Windows Store App not working

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I created a web service in Java that I plan to deploy on a Tomcat server. I plan on consuming this service from a Windows Store App. Unfortunately, I keep on getting some exceptions on both the server and client sides.

Here is a very simplified implementation of what I’m trying to achieve.

**Java Web Service**

Dependencies: JAX-WS version 2.2.8 found at https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/

I implemented a simple ‘Hello’ world java service. I use the publisher class to test the service without having Tomcat involved. Nevertheless, I have already tried the service within Tomcat and the errors are consistent no matter how I deploy it.

HelloWorld Code:

```
package com.test.service;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface HelloWorld {
    @WebMethod
    public String helloWorld(String name);
}
```

HelloWorldImpl Code:

```
package com.test.service;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.test.service.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    public String helloWorld(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Publisher Code:

```
package com.test.service;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Publisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8082/TEST/HelloWorld",new HelloWorldImpl());
    }
}
```

Here is the wsdl that it generated:

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.6. -->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://service.test.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"targetNamespace="http://service.test.com/"
    name="HelloWorldImplService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://service.test.com/"
            schemaLocation="http://localhost:8082/TEST/HelloWorld?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="helloWorld">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorld"/>
    </message>
    <message name="helloWorldResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorldResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="HelloWorld">
        <operation name="helloWorld">
            <input message="tns:helloWorld"/>
            <output message="tns:helloWorldResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="HelloWorldImplPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="helloWorld">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="HelloWorldImplService">
        <port name="HelloWorldImplPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldImplPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8082/TEST/HelloWorld"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Client Service Consumers

Dependencies: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

On the client side, I first implemented a simple ‘Windows form’ application to test the service. Here are the steps that I used to add the service:

1. Right click on project in solution explorer.
2. Select Add->Service Reference
3. Entered the URL in the ‘Address’ field.
4. Clicked ‘Go’.
5. Selected the service in the ‘Services’ List
6. Entered ‘HelloService’ in the Namespace field.
7. Clicked ‘Go’

Alternately, I could have tried adding a ‘Web Service’ by clicking the ‘Advanced’ button, and then clicking “Add Web Reference” in the dialog that opens. It does not matter, either way works fine.

Here is the lines of code to invoke the service:

```
HelloService.HelloWorldImplService service = new HelloService.HelloWorldImplService();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(service.helloWorld("World!"));
```

The above example prints out “Hello World!”

Now I wanted to try this out in a Windows Store App. So I created an app, and proceeded to add the service. Just like the Windows form app, I added the service as follow.

1. Right click on project in solution explorer.
2. Select Add->Service Reference
3. Entered the URL in the ‘Address’ field.
4. Clicked ‘Go’.
5. Selected the service in the ‘Services’ List
6. Entered ‘HelloService’ in the Namespace field.
7. Clicked ‘Go’

The code that it generated is slightly different than what was produced for the ‘Windows Form’ app. The methods create tasks to wait on the response. Here is the code to invoke the service:

```
HelloService.HelloWorldClient service = new HelloService.HelloWorldClient();
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HelloService.helloWorldResponse> task = service.helloWorldAsync("World!");
task.Wait();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(task.Result.ToString());
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work. First, I get an exception on the server side.

```
Dec 8, 2013 1:00:12 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:284)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:118)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:266)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:82)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:446)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:83)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:598)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:83)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:570)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

This is telling me that the server is expecting SOAP 1.1 while the client is using SOAP 1.2.

On the client side, I get the following message.

```
   InnerException: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
   HResult=-2146233087
   Message=There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8082/TEST/HelloWorld that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
   Source=System.ServiceModel.Internals
   StackTrace:
        at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        HResult=-2146233079
        Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
        Source=System
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
             at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStreamAsyncResult.CompleteGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult result)
        InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
             HResult=-2147467259
             Message=An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.1.100:8082
             Source=System
             ErrorCode=10013
             NativeErrorCode=10013
             StackTrace:
                  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                  at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

This makes sense since the web service failed to process the request.

Anyway, I have spent days trying to figure out this problem but can’t seem to find a solution.

So here are my question…

1. Why does the service work in a ‘Windows Form’ app, but not for a ‘Windows Store’ app?
2. And of course, how can I get around this problem?